# How can I remove a fix substring from a UNIX/Linux output?

Tags: linux, command-line, regex, sed, find-and-replace

My question looks ridicilously simple, but:

- I would like to remove an entire string, not a list of characters, so I can't use `tr`.
- I don't know the position of my substring, so I can't use `cut`.
- I'm not working with regular expressions, but my substring is a namespace, so it does contain dots, so I don't know how to work with `sed`.

The point is the following: I have the following lines:

```
2023-10-01 15:38:35.2545 | Info | Company.Customer.Server.Communication.Connection.ConnectionManager.SendNextTelegram | Message sent to Server: <HM><ID>25364205</ID><TC>CHR</TC><TR><ID>25906006</ID><DS><ID>GPR5_IN</ID></DS></TR></HM>
2023-10-01 15:38:35.6801 | Info | Company.Customer.Server.Communication.Connection.ConnectionManager.OnDataReceived | Telegram received from Server: <HM><ID>25364205</ID><TC>CHR</TC><RT>SUCCESS</RT><RC>0</RC><TR><ID>25906006</ID><DS><ID>GPR5_IN</ID></DS></TR></HM>
```

I would like to remove the namespace "Company.Customer.Server.Communication.Connection.".

On of the things I tried, is the following:

```
sed -e 's/"Company.Customer.Server.Communication.Connection.ConnectionManager"/""/g'
```

(I can imagine you say "But this is freaking easy, just disable regular expressions in `sed`", but the manpages only mentions the `-r` switch, which causes even more regular expressions to be used.)

Oh, I'm working on a Ubuntu WSL on a Windows computer.

Comment: Just remove the double quotes from your expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whith `sed` you do not need (in this case) double quotes so use:

```
sed -e 's/Company.Customer.Server.Communication.Connection.ConnectionManager//g'
```

Also you can use something like in `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub(/Company.Customer.Server.Communication.Connection.ConnectionManager/,"");print}'
```

Comment: I prefer using `sed`, I just need to remember not to use double quotes anymore.

Comment: To match the "literal" `.`, you really need `\.`. `.` IIRC means any single character. (But of course, practically speaking `.` is probably fine when what you need to match is itself "specific"/"special" enough.) /cc @Dominique